# How to fix INJECT_EVENT permission exception when sending touches to an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, emulation, instrumentation

Although there are many examples showing that something like this should work, the following code fails.
This code lives in a test project that is associated with the real project.

```
public class MyTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public MyTest(String name)
    {
        super("com.mypackage.activities", MyActivity.class);
        setName(name);
    }

    public void testTap() throws Throwable
    {
        //Required by MotionEvent.obtain according to JavaDocs
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        Instrumentation i = getInstrumentation();

        //Setup the info needed for our down and up events to create a tap
        MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 300, 20, 0);
        MotionEvent upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 300, 20, 0);

        //Send the down/up tap event
        i.sendPointerSync(downEvent);
        i.sendPointerSync(upEvent);

        //Delay to see the results
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
    }

}
```

This throws a
    java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
on the i.sendPointerSync() calls.
I have also tried view.onTouchEvent(event) and view.dispatchTouchEvent(event) without success.

The only thing I can think of is if the examples where this is working live in the project being tested. This seems bad because the recommendation is to separate tests to a different project and be able to run them from a build server with something like:

```
adb -e shell am instrument -w com.mypackage.activities.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Comment: You probably need a rooted device, check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635486/android-keyevent-injection-requires-system-permissions) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission).

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>

Comment: Your app has to be a system app to have the android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS permission.

Answer (score 3):

This probably means that your main project, your test project or your emulator versions are out of sync.

Answer (score -1):

It might help others.

Problem we got is

> Failed to perform gesture. java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to
>   another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission (RuntimeError")

In my case, the problem was with the

> Network not connected

. Once fixed the network connection issue, tests are started running.